# Rowversion comparison in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, rowversion

How should I compare `rowversion` fields using Entity Framework? I have one table which has a `rowversion` column, I want to get data from tables for which the row version is higher than specified value.

```
byte[] rowversion = ... some value;
 _context.Set<T>().Where(item => item.RowVersion > rowVersion);
```

This line does not work, it throws the error:

> *Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]'*

Any idea how I can compare `rowversion` fields in C#/Entity Framework?

Comment: With rowversion column, you can basically only check for equality (or non-equality) - you cannot really test for "larger than" or not.

Comment: @marc_s I thought so too, but actually, taking a closer look, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) speaks of rowversion values getting incremented, which supports the observation that a rowversion can be treated as a 64-bit integer, and higher values have been inserted into the database later, and it being a 64-bit integer would mean there is no realistic chance of overflow.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what we did to solve this. Use a compare extension like this:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkHelper
{
    public static int Compare(this byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
    {
        throw new Exception("This method can only be used in EF LINQ Context");
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
byte[] rowversion = .....somevalue;
_context.Set<T>().Where(item => item.RowVersion.Compare(rowversion) > 0);
```

The reason this works without a C# implementation is because the `Compare` extension method is never actually called, and EF LINQ simplifies `x.Compare(y) > 0` down to `x > y`.

Comment: This is truly sage magic and feels like a giant hack

Comment: Can confirm: Works in .NET 6.0. I'm stunned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is Kosher use of RowVersion ? What happens when it rolls over ?

I think you will need to convert it to string or int first. eg

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ba)
```

You can also call SPs from EF. :-)

Comment: Even if you could sustain 1 million inserts/updates per second for that one table continuously, it would roll over in about 584 thousand years if my math is right.

Answer (score 0):

Use EntitySQL.

```
// Drop down to ObjectContext and query against ObjectSet:
var objectContext = (dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
// Create param for EntitySQL
var param = new ObjectParameter("rowVersion", rowVersion);
// Create IQueryable<T>
var query = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>.Where("it.RowVersion > @rowVersion",param);
```