# Select new records by timestamp column with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, timestamp

I have a table with timestamp column (`RowId`) in my SQL Server database.

I want to query new rows according to this timestamp. The SQL query is following

```
SELECT *
 FROM [MyTable]
 where RowId>=0x0000000000A99B06
```

`0x0000000000A99B06` is a max timestamp value from the previous query.

How can I make such a query using Entity Framework database-first? `RowId` maps to `byte[]` property and I have no idea how to compare byte arrays in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Entity Framework because it does not allow the `>=` operator in timestamp comparisons. It only allows `=`. You can do e.g.

```cs
var b = BitConverter.GetBytes(1000000L);
var query = from x in MyTable
            where x.RowId = b; // not >=
```

But that would not be very useful. So you've got to find another way to get new rows, e.g. values in an identity column, or add a "real" time stamp (datetime) column.

Comment: Thank you.
In general, I can do it in the following way:

 (from x in MyTable
  where x.Id >
    (from k in MyTable
     where k.ROWID == b
     select k.Id).First()
  select x);

Answer (score 17):

Actually you can do small hack. It works for me 100%

```
internal static class EntityFrameworkHelper
{
   public static int Compare(this byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }  
}
```

And after that you can use it like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
   var messages = Set<Message>().Where(m => m.Modified.Compare(filter.TimeStamp) > 0).ToList();
}
```

It will eventually generate SQL syntax like this: "Select * from Messages Where Modified > @param). And it works. Exception is never thrown.

Comment: this is excellent solution for this problem. There is as well another more complicated solution that allows creating generic version of this if someone needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38152016/2645243

Comment: We have this same hack in our code-base. I don't know why EF just doesn't do the right thing out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use plain SQL with EntityFramework.

It can avoid additional inner query (see Gert Arnold's answer and my comment), but it looks like ugly.

```
long timeStamp = 100500;
IEnumerable<MyTable> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyTable>(String.Format("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ROWID>{0} ORDER BY RowId ASC", timeStamp));
```