# Optional Parameters in EntityFrameWork query

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, optional-parameters

My method signatures are as following. Only Id is mandatory, all other three parameters are option. I need to handle this in where clause. If optional ones are present then i need to add them to where clause otherwise query should be built on Id and whatever is available from Optional parameters

Secondly can we use rowVersion in comparison as specified in the query below. (rowVersion in Sql Server is a time stamp)

```
GetRecords(int  Id, int[] LocationId = null, int PayrollNo = 0, byte[] rowVersion=null)

 {

     var result = this.context.employees.where(x=>x.Id == id && LocationId.Contains(x.locationId) && x.payrollNo ==PayrollNo && x.rowVersion >  rowVersion);

}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GetRecords(int  Id, int[] LocationId = null, int PayrollNo = 0, byte[] rowVersion=null)

 {

     var result = this.context.employees.where(x=>x.Id == id);
     if (LocationId != null)
         result = result.Where(x=>LocationId.Contains(x.locationId));
     if (PayrollNo > 0)
         result = result.Where(x=>x.payrollNo == PayrollNo);
     if (rowVersion != null)
         result = result.Where(x=>x.rowVersion >  rowVersion);

}
```

Comment: Can we compare RowVersion like this ? My Entity represents RowVersion as byte[ ] whereas it's a timestamp in SQL Server

Comment: Looks like you might need a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761114/select-new-records-by-timestamp-column-with-entity-framework