# Pass timestamp to sql server where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am trying to pass a timestamp to sql server where clause but it's not working due to incompatible type.

Can anyone help me? pls..

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Timestamp", "0x000000253A0B0FE2"));
```

Comment: what Type is `Timestamp` in your database / procedure?

Comment: it is TimeStamp type column in my table

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146023/converting-sql-server-rowversion-to-long-or-ulong

Comment: i have got the clue.. thanks everyone...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to incorrect data types in C# code. Below is the fixed code...

```
byte[] _timeStamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x0);

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Timestamp", _timeStamp));

_timeStamp = (byte[])ds.Tables[2].Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: Please strive to include as much information in your posts in future. Not everyone is an advanced user.