# how to convert ulong to rowversion

Tags: c#, sql, rowversion

reference to [converting sql server rowversion to long or ulong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146023/converting-sql-server-rowversion-to-long-or-ulong/38149945#38149945)
i can convert SQL RowVersion to ulong by code:

```
static ulong BigEndianToUInt64(byte[] bigEndianBinary)
{
    return ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[0] << 56) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[1] << 48) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[2] << 40) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[3] << 32) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[4] << 24) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[5] << 16) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[6] <<  8) |
                   bigEndianBinary[7];
}
```

Now, I am faced with a problem, how to convert ulong to byte [8]?
I save the value of rowversion to a file, then read it and use it to make the query. the query parameter should be byte[] , not ulong . otherwise , there is an error will be raised.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: If you're using .NET Core 2.1+, you can use `BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt64BigEndian` instead of that custom method, and use `BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt64BigEndian` to go the other way

Comment: @canton7 , thanks .  i'm using .net 4.5.

Comment: Support for .NET Framework 4.5 ended in **2016**! Get yourself onto something which at least has security fixes!

Comment: @canton7. yes it supports. but , it's not a good idea adding too much dll to the project while we just need only two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got an answer from [BigEndian.GetBytes Method (Int64)](https://www.gridprotectionalliance.org/NightlyBuilds/GridSolutionsFramework/Help/html/M_GSF_BigEndian_GetBytes_8.htm)

thanks all.

```
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this ulong value)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            (byte)(value >> 56),
            (byte)(value >> 48),
            (byte)(value >> 40),
            (byte)(value >> 32),
            (byte)(value >> 24),
            (byte)(value >> 16),
            (byte)(value >> 8),
            (byte)(value)
        };
    }
```