# rowVersion gets mapped to byte[8] in Entityframe work but when manually casting it's byte[18]

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, rowversion

I am getting `rowVersion` from database as `byte[8]`

```
var rowVersion= new MyContext().Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id).rowVersion;
// suppose above the actual databse values is 0x0000000000038B8C
var rowVersionToLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(rowVersion,0);
```

Now if i manually do this:

```
String rowversionStr = "0x0000000000038B8C";
byte[] mybyteArray = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rowversionStr);
```

This gives me `byte[18]` and when i convert it to `Int64` it gives me different value.

i am not getting this.

I want to pass `rowVersion` as parameter to `WebApi` get method. As `Byte[]` is not allowed so i am passing it as a string

Update:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get(string rowVersion, int id)
    {

        var exisitingRowVersion = long.Parse(rowVersion.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var result = new MyContext().employees.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == 2 && BitConverter.ToInt64(x.RowVersion, 0) > exisitingRowVersion);

        return Ok(result);
```

Not getting why this one doesn't work. We are basically comparing long with long

Comment: The correct way would be `long.Parse("0x0000000000038B8C".Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`... But even `long` aren't fully supported by Javascript, so I wouldn't pass out a `long`... You could pass out directly the `string` value.

Comment: basically string gets mapped to my webapi parameter. string is basically rowVersion stored in Sql Server database now i want to perform this.context.employee.where(x=>(BitConverter.ToInt64(x.rowVersion,0)> rowVersionParameter)). Here i cant compare long with the string value. What i do is i try to create a byte[] from string to compare it with database value. But that's not working. when i convert it to byte[] it returns byte[18]

Comment: Well long.Parse("0x0000000000038B8C".Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);looks like a valid answer

Comment: But you can't use it in the query... You can't map the `RowVersion` type to a `long`... it seems to be compatible only with `byte[]`... but you can't do the `>` with `byte[]`... see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/7437970/613130

Comment: added an update to original question. Still not getting why long is not getting compared with long?

Answer (score 4):

You have three major problems. It shouldn't be this complicated, but it is.

Here is the solution I use: [Timestamp.cs](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/929d194c87df8ad0438f6cab0139a0a6). It's way easier. I'll put an example at the end.

#### 1. Not comparing apples to apples

`rowVersion` is an 8-byte array. Each byte represents a **section of a 64-bit integer** and will be 0 - 255.

`System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes` encodes ASCII strings, not integers. It returns an 18-byte array. Each byte represents **a textual character** and will be '0' (48) - '9' (57), 'A' (65) - 'F' (70), or 'x' (120).

Solution: you're on the right track with `long.Parse("0x0000000000038B8C".Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

#### 2. SQL Server timestamps are stored big-endian

`BitConverter.ToUInt64` is either big-endian or little-endian, depending on whether you're running on a system where `ulong` is big-endian or little-ending. You can [see this for yourself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,90). You need a conversion that will always be big-endian regardless of the system you are running on:

```
static ulong BigEndianToUInt64(byte[] bigEndianBinary)
{
    return ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[0] << 56) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[1] << 48) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[2] << 40) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[3] << 32) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[4] << 24) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[5] << 16) |
           ((ulong)bigEndianBinary[6] <<  8) |
                   bigEndianBinary[7];
}
```

#### 3. Binary comparisons are unsigned

When SQL Server compares `0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF < 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is bigger. To keep the same meaning that SQL Server treats it with, you must use `ulong` **and not `long`**. Otherwise `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` becomes `-1L` rather than what SQL Server considers it as, `ulong.MaxValue`.

Granted, 9 quadrillion things have to happen before the high bit of a `timestamp` column gets used, but you might use the same code to compare two `binary(8)` timestamps that were generated some other way. The important thing is to duplicate SQL Server's comparison behavior.

#### The cleanest solution

Here is the solution I use: [Timestamp.cs](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/929d194c87df8ad0438f6cab0139a0a6).

Your code becomes:

```
var existingRowVersion = (Timestamp)ulong.Parse(rowVersion.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var result = new MyContext().employees.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == 2 && (Timestamp)x.RowVersion > exisitingRowVersion);
```

Basically once you cast to `Timestamp`, you can't go wrong.

<del>Sadly, no matter which method you use, there's no good way to apply this filter on the server-side instead of the client side. That's the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437970/how-to-query-code-first-entities-based-on-rowversion-timestamp-value).</del> Guess what I discovered! [A way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152016/521757) with Entity Framework 6.1.3! How cool is that?

**HOWEVER**, and this is unrelated to your question, you should absolutely put the `Id == 2` filter on the server side (before you call ToList). Otherwise you are transferring the entire table to your application and then discarding all but one row on the client side. You should do this:

```
var existingRowVersion = (Timestamp)ulong.Parse(rowVersion.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var result = new MyContext().employees.Where(x => x.Id == 2).ToList().Where((Timestamp)x.RowVersion > exisitingRowVersion);
```

Best:

```
var existingRowVersion = (Timestamp)ulong.Parse(rowVersion.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var employee = new MyContext().employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);
if (employee == null) ... // Deleted
else if ((Timestamp)employee.RowVersion > exisitingRowVersion) ... // Updated
```

Answer (score 2):

Before, short story:

For me works to convert from "AAAxxx==" to byte array using `Convert.FromBase64String` and vice versa.

Long story:

In my case I get from SQL 2016 DB the output of complex object including RowVersion from a query that uses FOR JSON PATH and [SQL transform RowVersion in string base 64 and dates to string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-converts-sql-server-data-types-to-json-data-types-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and use that output direct as a result but when is used as request pay load as is in MVCx or WCF fails because they works well with rowversion transform like an output serialized from object to JSON like WCF or MVCx does: rowversion as byte array and date as /Date(###). 
In order to convert from output of JSON-SQL to JSON-MVC-WCF compatible I have to transform the response before the outout in the server using an extension that convert in this case for RowVersion with an example value of AAAxxx== to [0,0,0,#,#,#] and for that pass AAAxxx== as the parameter for Convert.FromBase64String and iterate the byte array to output the expected result.

Comment: This shouldn't be flagged as "not an answer". Firstly because this flag *only* applies to answers that don't even try to be an answer. Secondly, because `Convert.FromBase64String` and `Convert.ToBase64String` are exactly the methods to be used in Rowversion/String conversion. The only thing is, it could be explained a bit more extensively.